# could any one help me finding the Error with SP

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
create function Fun12(@InsCd varchar)
returns varchar(100)
as 
begin
declare @ret varchar(52)
set @ret = (select [InsName] from [Assignment4].[dbo].[1466] 
   where rtrim(ltrim([InsCd]))= @InsCd)
return @ret
end
```

Executing:

```
declare @r varchar(50)
exec @r = dbo.Fun12 '436'

select @r
```

I am getting `NULL` value.
Could any one please help me finding the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a size for your parameter `@InsCd`.

Some thing like this but you might want to use another value than `20` depending on the size of field `InsCd`.

```
create function Fun12(@InsCd varchar(20))
```

Comment: but `varchar(1)` is the best datatype ever. Has anyone ever worked out why 1 was deemed to obviously be the best default value?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should make sure that the code contained by the function actually returns something when you run it directly in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS):

```
-- SQL
select InsName from [1466] where rtrim(ltrim([InsCd])) = '436';
```

In this case, I would use a stored procedure rather than a function. You could also use the SSMS Profiler (Tools > Profiler) to monitor the traffic to SQL Server. This way, you can actually see what gets executed, see the parameters for SPs, etc.